# Iterating arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to iterate over multiple arrays and return different values from each one?

Ex:

```
{
"gameQuestion": [
    "English League Championship: What will be the match result?",
    "2017 Boston Marathon: Which COUNTRY will the MEN'S WINNER represent?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "English League Championship (Huddersfield Town @ Derby County): Will Derby SCORE in the 2nd Half?",
    "English Premier League: What will be the match result?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "NBA Eastern Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Cavaliers lead 1-0): Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "NBA (IND@CLE): Which PLAYER will SCORE a HIGHER PERCENTAGE of their TEAM'S TOTAL POINTS in the 1st Half?",
    "NHL Eastern Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Series tied 1-1): Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "NHL Eastern Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Series tied 1-1): Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "NBA (IND@CLE): Will a 3-POINTER be MADE in the FIRST 2 MINUTES of the 3rd Quarter?",
    "NBA Western Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Spurs lead 1-0): What will be the GAME RESULT?",
    "NHL Western Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Predators lead 2-0): Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "NHL Western Conference Playoffs - 1st Rd (Ducks lead 2-0): Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?",
    "MLB: Who will WIN this matchup?"
],
"propVal": [
    "m57338o58525",
    "m57338o58526",
    "m57336o58521",
    "m57336o58522",
    "m57329o4111",
    "m57329o12",
    "m57316o793",
    "m57316o726",
    "m57319o58515",
    "m57319o58516",
    "m57322o423",
    "m57322o461",
    "m57323o517",
    "m57323o515",
    "m57327o206",
    "m57327o15",
    "m57330o14",
    "m57330o35",
    "m57331o21",
    "m57331o148",
    "m57298o27453",
    "m57298o112",
    "m57320o58517",
    "m57320o58518",
    "m57318o58513",
    "m57318o58514",
    "m57325o481",
    "m57325o479",
    "m57326o463",
    "m57326o5964",
    "m57333o19384",
    "m57333o78",
    "m57334o3",
    "m57334o5"
],
"info": [
    "Opponents",
    " Aston Villa: Win or Draw",
    "@ Fulham: Win",
    "Kenya",
    " Any Other Country",
    " Tampa Bay Rays (6-7) Snell",
    " @ Boston Red Sox (7-5) Wright",
    " Yes: Derby Scores 1+ Goals in 2nd Half",
    " No: No Derby Goal in 2nd Half",
    " Arsenal: Win",
    " @ Middlesbrough: Win or Draw",
    " Chicago White Sox (6-5) Holland",
    " @ New York Yankees (8-4) Montgomery",
    " Indiana Pacers (42-40)",
    " @ Cleveland Cavaliers (51-31)",
    " Paul George (IND)",
    " LeBron James (CLE) or Tie",
    " Ottawa Senators (44-28-10)",
    " @ Boston Bruins (44-31-7)",
    " Washington Capitals (55-19-8)",
    " @ Toronto Maple Leafs (40-27-15)",
    " Pittsburgh Pirates (6-6) Nova",
    " @ St. Louis Cardinals (3-9) Lynn",
    " Milwaukee Brewers (7-6) Anderson",
    " @ Chicago Cubs (6-6) Lackey",
    " Cleveland Indians (5-7) Salazar",
    " @ Minnesota Twins (7-5) Gibson",
    " Los Angeles Angels (6-7) Chavez",
    " @ Houston Astros (8-4) Morton",
    " Yes: 3PM in First 2 Min of 3rd Qtr",
    " No: No 3PM in First 2 Min of 3rd Qtr",
    " Grizzlies: Win or Single Digit Loss",
    " @ Spurs: Win By Double Digits",
    " Chicago Blackhawks (50-23-9)",
    " @ Nashville Predators (41-29-12)",
    " Anaheim Ducks (46-23-13)",
    " @ Calgary Flames (45-33-4)",
    " Miami Marlins (7-5) Koehler",
    " @ Seattle Mariners (5-8) Miranda",
    " Arizona Diamondbacks (8-5) Ray",
    " @ Los Angeles Dodgers (7-6) McCarthy"
]
```

}

and I want to iterate over all three at the same time, but return

`["English League Championship: What will be the match result?", Aston Villa: Win or Draw","@ Fulham: Win",m57338o58525",m57338o58526]` then `[2017 Boston Marathon: Which COUNTRY will the MEN'S WINNER represent?","Kenya"," Any Other Country","m57336o58521",
    "m57336o58522"]`  and on b I need to skip the first element.

```
var json = require('./output.json');

var a = json.gameQuestion;
var b = json.info;
var c = json.propVal;
var res= [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
res.push([a[i],b[i*2+1],b[i*2+2],c[i*2],c[i*2+1]]);
}
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2]);
console.log(res[3]);
console.log(res[4]);
console.log(res[5]);
```

I've got the first iteration, but ever time I add another for loop it just ends up returning j the same amount of times as the length of the first for loop.

Update: Thanks! This problem is solved!

Comment: Can you please share any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: There is totally a way to do that. How would you do that manually on a piece of paper, if you were asked to do that?

Comment: I've tried ``forEach`` and nested for loops

Comment: @tin10 Please share that code in question

Comment: var b = [a,4,5,6,7,8,9] is not a valid array at all unless a is a variable

Comment: @VinodLouis: It is in the example: `var a = [1,2,3,]`.

Comment: @VinodLouis sorry i just threw a in there to make a point. I just don't want the first value of the second variable to be included.

Comment: `a.map((x, i) => [x].concat(b.slice(i*2+1, i*2+3)).concat(c.slice(i*2, i*2+2)))` - https://jsfiddle.net/eww60r6o/

Comment: @tin10 you always want to skip 1st element of `b` of is there a pattern to it?

Comment: @MattWay: Or just `a.map((x, i) => [x].concat(b.slice(i*2+1, i*2+3), c.slice(i*2, i*2+2)))`

Comment: @FelixKling Good pickup. I really have just always wanted to fit a seemingly complex answer into a comment...

Comment: @MattWay: Spread works too: `a.map((x, i) => [x, ...b.slice(i*2+1, i*2+3), ...c.slice(i*2, i*2+2)])`. You should make it an answer :)

Comment: @FelixKling That's the best one :p

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i didn't get you wrong, check this

```js
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [69,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var c = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
var res= [];
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
res.push([a[i],b[i*2+1],b[i*2+2],c[i*2],c[i*2+1]]);
}
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2]);
```

Comment: Please add explanation as you are answering for readers and not just OP. What have you changed, Why have you changed etc.

Comment: This fits what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 or 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [69,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var c = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
//Since for each value in array a you need a different value in array b in a single iteration we will use different pointers for each array but value will be dependent on i     
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var final = [];
    j = 2*i+1; //j is the pointer that iterates over array 'b'
    k = 2*i; //k iterates over array 'c'

    final.push(a[i]);
    final.push(b[j]);
    final.push(b[j+1]);
    final.push(c[k]);
    final.push(c[k+1]);
    console.log(final);
}
```